# What's required to make the mirror modifier work properly?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I was working on a model when I realized something happened to the mirror modifier and it wasn't showing anymore. Tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but couldn't go back that far. So my question is there a way to apply the mirror modifier again?

Here is what i mean: [image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

I tried to make it work but the right half of my model doesn't mirror properly anymore.

Comment: Hello :). Your *Origin point* is off center. Just move it back and it should work again.

Comment: thank you very much